# How to mount an external HDD?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have Ubuntu Linux 12.04 version the latest right now.I want to mount an external HDD NTFS 1TB.I have followed many guides but still no success.The error I'm getting is this:

```
Failed to read last sector (1953523119): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
Using Storage Device MAnager i get this error:Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mount: only root can mount /dev/sdb1 on /media/Skliros_Diskos {external disk name}
```

When I use `sudo fdisk -l`, this is the output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e0bc6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   618854399   309426176   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       618856446   625141759     3142657    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       618856448   625141759     3142656   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000202043392 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121600 cylinders, total 1953519616 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002093a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  1953525167   976761560    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: Is it a NTFS5 volume?

Comment: Its file system is NTFS

Answer (score 90):

Try to see if there is an entry in the disk list with

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Then try mounting it with

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /media
```

To find the correct `/dev/sdb` location for your external drive look at the result of `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: More detailed please i am an absolute beginner on this OS.But i will try these instructions

Comment: I tried and i get the same error

Comment: for partitioned drives, use `sudo parted -l` instead of `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: I have a GNU/Linux (ext4) partition, this command worked for me: ```sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/ -t ext4```

Comment: I have tried the two commands provided in this answer. Here is the result that I obtain, "NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
"  Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Answer (score 30):

#### Step 1: Create a folder

```
sudo mkdir /media/Skliros_Diskos
```

#### Step 2: Mount NTFS filesystem

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/Skliros_Diskos
```

Please note the spaces. As per your comment on the question, you did not add spaces in the command.

You should not mount it on the `/media` directory, since the system might use it thus might not allow you to `umount` the disk easily. Another reason is, when you plug-in another external drive, Ubuntu will automatically create a directory in the `/media` and mount the system on that directory, which could probably have some side effects, as the `/media` directory would be your external drive.

Once mounted, you can access it normally through Nautilus (The default Ubuntu GUI file browser). It should be listed in the list on the left side, if it isn't, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and type `/media/Skliros_Diskos`.

Or you access it in the terminal with `cd /media/Skliros_Diskos`.

Comment: I used the command of step 2 and i get the same error.I copy/pasted it to be sure.I didn't made it on mounting it so i can't follow the next steps

Comment: @Slash Are you sure your NTFS volume isn't corrupted? `sudo ntfsck /dev/sdb1`, this command will scan an NTFS volume for errors, are there any?

Comment: i get the the same error with before

Comment: When i use this command "sudo ntfsck /dev/sdb1 " I get the same error with this command "sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/Skliros_Diskos"

Comment: I tried to mount the volume of skliros_diskos from disk utility i get another error which is this:Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
Unprivileged user can not mount NTFS block devices using the external FUSE
library. Either mount the volume as root, or rebuild NTFS-3G with integrated
FUSE support and make it setuid root. Please see more information at
http://tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#unprivileged

Comment: Come on i have submitted so much info.There must be a solution

Comment: @Slash I understand your rush, I really do, but please you have to be patient a bit. Try running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ntfs-3g` and the try remounting the volume, after it's done reinstalling. If that also fails, try mounting with the following command: `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o umask=000,user /dev/sdb1 /media/Skliros_Diskos`

Comment: i tried and done whatever you said .. still it isn't  working

Comment: In this case, I believe your NTFS might be damaged. Do you have access to a Windows installation, where you can try plug-in the NTFS drive on it? Whether it works or not, you should do a file system check on the drive.

Comment: Tell me the correct way please on how to do that

Comment: I do not have access to any Windows installation near me, and it's been a while since I accessed one. But I'll help you with what I can remember. After you plug it into a Windows machine, open the `My Computer` folder, locate your external drive and right click it. After that, click on `Properties`. There will be a `Check disk` button or something in that meaning in the properties page, click it and a small window will appear. Tick the `Automatically fix errors` checkbox and click OK. After error checking is done, try mounting it again on Ubuntu.

Comment: Its okay i found a software called "CheckDisk" which allow me to copy data from my external HDD i don't know what wrong with this HDD but i got what i wanted done thanks for all

Comment: TestDisk i meant

Comment: @Slash If you found an answer for your problem, please do post what you did by answering your own question and marking it as the correct answer so maybe it would help future visitors.

Comment: Actually it isn't exactly the answer in the problem.I found a program which is called "TestDisk" i followed a guide on youtube .its pretty simple .So with it i copied some files i wanted from the HDD thats all

Comment: I wish people would have read this guy's comments.  His problem and solution are stated when he says "Unprivileged user can not mount NTFS block devices using the external FUSE library. Either mount the volume as root, or rebuild NTFS-3G with integrated FUSE support and make it setuid root. "  Anyway the answers to this question were helpful to me solving my own problem.

Comment: @Jistanidiot It would be great if you can input your own answer on how to do it!

Comment: @Dan as I pointed out "Either mount the volume as root, or rebuild NTFS-3G with integrated FUSE support and make it setuid root."

Comment: I have tried the command indicated in this solution, the result that I obtain is, "NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
" Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: @MichaelLevy It should be the partition, not the whole disk, for example, `/dev/sda2`.

Answer (score 21):

I find more cosy the use of `lsblk` instead of `fdisk -l` even because recently it is not always needed to specify the file system type *a priory*.
Moreover I want to mimic the behaviour of  the mounting through *Device Notifier* with the command line. Tested on Kubuntu 14.04 LTS.

**Step 1: Individuate from where**

To individuate where is I prefer to use `lsblk` (from `util-linux` package)

```
lsblk
```

That gives something like

```
 NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 925.5G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0     6G  0 part [SWAP]

sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0   1.8T  0 part
```

In this case, the external hard drive that I am attempting to mount is referred to as `sdb1`. Note that the external drive is not mounted (because the MOUNTPOINT entry is blank), and, importantly, if I unplug the external hard drive, then I will not see the entry `sdb1` anymore.

**Step 2: mount**

If I want to mount it in an existing directory `/Full/path/` and my user id `uid =1000` and my group id is `gid=1000` I can use directly

```
sudo mount  /dev/sdb1 /Full/path/ -o uid=1000,gid=1000,utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137
```

That gives me the same mounting option that I have when I mount  it graphically through the *Device Notifier*

**Notes:**

- You can see your uid:gid with `grep $USER /etc/passwd` : are respectively the 3rd and the 4th field separated by `:`
- `man mount` for all the mount options

Answer (score 2):

**Ubuntu 18.04.5**,
To mount and/or unmount a disk from the shell prompt (Terminal)
in the same fashion as an external disk gets mounted "automagically".
*(e.g. /media/$USER/Disk-Label/ )*

Prerequisite: the disk is visible as "disk" and possibly also as "part" in the output of;
`$ lsblk`
e.g.

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
...
sdb           8:16   0   2,7T  0 disk 
└─sdb1        8:17   0     2T  0 part 
...
```

Then it will look like this:

```
$ udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sdb1
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-other-seat ===
Authentication is required to mount WDC WD30EZRX-00DC0B0 (/dev/sdb1)
Authenticating as: $USER,,, ($USER)
Password: **********  
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
Mounted /dev/sdb1 at /media/$USER/USB-exfat.

$ ls -l /media/$USER
total nnn
drwxrwxrwx 1 $USER $USER 131072 jan  1  1970 USB-exfat

$ ls -lA /media/$USER/USB-exfat
total 0

$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
...
sdb           8:16   0   2,7T  0 disk 
└─sdb1        8:17   0     2T  0 part /media/$USER/USB-exfat

$ udisksctl unmount --block-device /dev/sdb1  
...
Unmounted /dev/sdb1.

$
```

Where `$USER` will be the login name of the current user, assuming that user is present is among those specified by `sudoers` (e.g. admin[?] and sudo group members).

---

*exfat partitions:

`sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`*