# Which type of partition should I specify for an external hard drive used exclusivly for backing up data?

Tags: partitioning, backup, external-hdd

**Context**

I am trying to use an external hard drive to backup my data. I have a 2.0 TB drive and I have identified its name using the information I found in [1].  It turns out that the disk is unallocated (whatever that truly means I have no idea). Looking at [2], I understand that I have to create a new partition. Quoting [2], I understand that

> Create New Partition
> To create new partition, issue again the following command at the shell prompt:
> sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
> At the “Command (m for help)” prompt, type “n” to create a new partition, then type “p” to make it a primary partition. Next, type the number “1” to indicate a that this is the first primary partition on the drive. Then type “t” to specify partition type; here you are going to be asked a hexadecimal number that indicates whether the partition is fat32, ext3, ext4, etc, for example if we want an ext3 partition we would enter “83“. You can get a complete list of identifiers by typing “L” at the “Command (m for help)” prompt.
> The following table lists some of the most common ones:
> 82  Linux swap / So
> 83  Linux (ext2, ext3, ext4, etc.)
> 85  Linux extended  c7  Syrinx
> 6  FAT16
> b  FAT32
> 7  HPFS/NTFS
> 8e  Linux LVM
> a5  FreeBSD
> a6  OpenBSD
> a9  NetBSD
> af  HFS / HFS+

**My Questions**

Which type of partition type should I specify for the purpose here, which is to have an external hard drive for the sole purpose of backing up my data?

**Bibliography**

[1] [How to mount an external HDD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177825/how-to-mount-an-external-hdd/613803#613803)

[2] https://www.geekyprojects.com/ubuntu/how-to-format-a-usb-external-hard-drive-for-linux/

Comment: Use Gparted to create and format your partition.

Comment: Best to use gpt partitioning, which you have to change first. With gparted select gpt under device, advanced over msdos(MBR) default partitioning before starting. All my data drives also have a smaller Ubuntu install for emergency boot. So I add an ESP, FAT32 100 to 500MB & / ( ext4). Then I add data partition(s) as ext4. Only if using Windows may you also want NTFS. But NTFS does not support Linux ownership & permissions,  so if backing up Linux data use a Linux format.

Comment: If you will only be using the drive on Linux, use an ext4 filesystem. If you want to be able to use the drive on Windows, use NTFS. ext4 works better with Linux (faster, supports Linux file permissions, etc) but Windows can't read it at all. However, Linux is capable of using NTFS (Windows's file system), so if you need Windows support use that.

Comment: Acceptable but not ideal. Please read oldfred's comment again.

Comment: When you select Creat partition table the next you have to do is to select the partitioning type and from a list you should select GPT. It's this simple.

Comment: I put Linux on my backup drives (USB3) and then have the choice of just saving files on them or even booting them if the need arises.  The space used on the drive is not that much for the system. I boot them about every 6 months to update the system.