# About mountiung external drive on Ubuntu 20.04 Lts

Tags: 20.04, mount, hard-drive

how to mount and use external hard drive on Ubuntu 20.04 Lts from terminal

Comment: [Here you go](https://askubuntu.com/a/177833/1222991) 

Comment: That doesn't help on Ubuntu 20.04 Lts, please suggest. And I want to access the external drive from Ubuntu terminal. Which isn't happening, but the external drive is mounted.